# Remove item from wininit

Tags: windows, outlook, outlook-2013

Every time a user logs into windows, Outlook will launch.  I could not find it listed in any of the standard startup folders or startup items.  I used Process Explorer to try to pinpoint what was starting Outlook.  I found that it was starting as a service under wininit,  how can I remove it from starting up without uninstall office?

[image: Outlook]

Answer (score 0):

Your probably have some service that uses the Outlook Object Model (Outlook cannot be used from a service). Note the process id and look at the services running under the same process id under the Services tab in the Task Manager.

Comment: There is no PID near it or a process with the same PID.  The parent process is listed as svchost.exe -k Dcomlaunch.

Answer (score 0):

Great utility from Microsoft called autoruns which according to them 'has the most comprehensive knowledge of any startup monitor' should help you get to the bottom of this.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx

Comment: Wow, this is a great app.  ONe I will all to my tool kit for sure.  But did not find out what is starting outlook.